Automatically creating products with sanity webhook on stripe, failing to pull price_id
I have a partly successful webhook that will automatically trigger a product creation in stripe for me syncing the title, sizes(and prices linked to them).
What I am struggling with is the price_id that is created being sent back to sanity and populating my price_id field to complete the synchronization.
Here is my webhook:
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY as string, {
  apiVersion: '2024-06-20',
});

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const { _id, title, sizes, image } = await req.json();

    if (!title) {
      console.log('Missing required param: name.');
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Missing required param: name.' }, { status: 400 });
    }

    console.log('Received product data:', { _id, title, sizes, image });

    let stripeProduct;
    try {
      stripeProduct = await stripe.products.retrieve(_id);
      console.log('Product already exists in Stripe:', stripeProduct.id);
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error.code === 'resource_missing') {

        stripeProduct = await stripe.products.create({
          id: _id,
          name: title,
          images: [image],  
          metadata: {
            sanity_id: _id,
          },
        });
        console.log('Created new Stripe product:', stripeProduct.id);
      } else {
        throw error; 
      }
    }

    
    for (const size of sizes) {
      const { size: sizeName, price, price_id, _id: sizeId } = size;
      console.log('Size object received:', size);

      console.log('Processing size:', { sizeName, price, price_id, sizeId });
      

      if (!sizeId) {
        console.error('Size ID is missing for this size:', size);
        continue; 
      }

      if (price_id) {
        console.log('Price ID exists, creating a new price...');
        const newPrice = await stripe.prices.create({
          unit_amount: price * 100,
          currency: 'gbp',
          product: stripeProduct.id,
        });

        await updateSanityPriceId(sizeId, newPrice.id);
      } else {
        console.log('No Price ID, creating a new price...');
        const newPrice = await stripe.prices.create({
          unit_amount: price * 100,
          currency: 'gbp',
          product: stripeProduct.id,
        });

        await updateSanityPriceId(sizeId, newPrice.id);
      }
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Product and prices synced with Stripe successfully.' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error syncing with Stripe:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

async function updateSanityPriceId(sizeId: string, priceId: string) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID}.api.sanity.io/v2024-06-20/data/mutate/production`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SANITY_WRITE_TOKEN}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        mutations: [
          {
            patch: {
              _id: sizeId,
              set: { price_id: priceId },
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
    });

    const result = await response.json();
    if (result.error) {
      console.error('Error from Sanity:', result.error);
    } else {
      console.log('Updated Sanity with new price ID:', result);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating Sanity with new price ID:', error);
  }
}

This is the error I keep getting:
Size ID is missing for this size: { size: '10x10', price: 100, lookup_key: null, price_id: null }

As far as I am aware every field receives an _id.. When I query in sanity vision it indeed shows an _id.
Thank you in advance for any help given.
I tried to destructure multiple ways.

I'm struggling to grasp your code and your intent. Product and Price objects are separate in Stripe's API and require controlling both cleanly. You should read https://docs.stripe.com/products-prices/how-products-and-prices-work carefully
Here you have a complex webhook handler with your own business logic and don't really explain what is failing, what size is and what you seem to expect. You'd likely be better off asking Stripe for help, sharing real object is and explaining what's not working: https://support.stripe.com/contact

@koopajah. I have an ecomm site where it sells prints, each print has 3 sizes and each size has 1 price, you can probably imagine how intensive it would be to manually add to sanity and stripe and manutally sync them everytime, especially when there are hundreds of them. My goal is to dynamically add the prints(products if you like) dynamically as they are created in sanity.

It's still really hard to map that to your code and your error(s). You'd be better off talking to Stripe's support team for 1:1 help.
